# How to use Regular Expression with NSPredicates?

Tags: objective-c, regex, nspredicate, nsregularexpression

In my app, I am trying to find list of strings which starts with any of the special characters(*,~,",().I want to use NSPredicate to find the these strings but I do not know what regular expression to create and use.Even I do not know how to use regular expression along with nspredicate.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString *str = @"*Hello";
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES '[*~\"()].+'"];
if ([pred evaluateWithObject:str]) {
    NSLog(@"Yes");
}
```

Comment: When I am providing this predicate it is crashing and displaying Log as "Unable to parse the format string "SELF MATCHES [*~"()].+"'".

Comment: @NuzhatZari Sorry, I forgot to put single quotes around the regexp. This should work.

Comment: I am using following predicate:NSPredicate *thePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Name beginswith[cd] '[*%~].+'"];NSMutableArray *theSearchedArray=[[theReceiptArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:thePredicate] mutableCopy];Still there is no result even if there are strings which starts with *.I have array and I want to find strings which starts with these characters.

Comment: @NuzhatZari You should use `@"Name MATCHES '[*%~].+'"` predicate instead of `@"Name beginswith[cd] '[*%~].+'"`.

Comment: Thanks dasblinkenlight for your answer.But still I am confused can this check whether my strings starts with these characters?and If I give more than 3 characters it crashes showing message: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Can't do regex matching, reason: Can't open pattern U_REGEX_INVALID_RANGE.

Comment: @NuzhatZari Did you include a minus sign `-` in the range? If you did, move it to the end of the sequence to be the last character before the closing square bracket `]`.

Comment: Thank you dasblinkenlight it is working.Yes you are write I was including - sign in between the list.But if I want to check whether name starts from special characters or number 0-9, then how I can include numbers in the regex along with special characters?

Comment: @NuzhatZari You can include digits with the exact syntax from your question - `[0-9*~\"()-]`. The reason you needed to move the dash `-` to the end of the expression is that it has special meaning inside square brackets: when it has characters on both its sides, it makes them into a range. The character on the left must appear before the character on the right in the ASCII table. `0-9` means *all digits*, `a-z` means *all lowercase letters*, `a-zA-Z` means *all letters*, and so on.

Comment: Oh..Thanks, now I got the reason.Yes it is working properly now.